# How to set the rate limiter dynamically in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, dynamic, rate-limiting

I need to set the rate limiter dynamically in Laravel 8 based on the combination of parameters stored in a database table:

| S.No | Key | Param 1 | Param 2 | Param 3 | Rate limit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | adx | param_1_a | param_2_d | param_3_x | 20 |
| 2 | buz | param_1_b | param_2_u | param_3_z | 30 |
| 3 | cfy | param_1_c | param_2_f | param_3_y | 40 |

and rate limiter code will be as follows:

```
protected function configureRateLimiting()
{
   RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
      return [
        Limit::perMinute(rateLimit)->by(RateLimitKey)->response(function () {
        ...
        }),
        Limit::perMinute(rateLimit1)->by(RateLimitKey1)->response(function () {
        ...
        }),
      ];
   });
}
```

I need to add the rate limiter to the array returned in the above code.

RateLimit value will be the value of the column "Rate Limit" from database table.

RateLimitKey will the value with combination of the columns Key, Param 1, Param 2, Param 3 (e.g., key_param1_param2_param_3)

Need to add the rate limiter dynamically using the data retrieved from the database table.

I am not sure about how to proceed on adding the rate limiter in Laravel 8.

Comment: What does the key represent in the database?

Comment: It is a parameter exists in a request

Answer (score 2):

You have the request in the context, so from here it is just about getting out the data from the `DB`. I'm assuming they are query parameters. Remember that this can be null, and needs to have a fallback.

```
DB::table('rate_limiting_table')
    ->where('key', $request->query('key'))
    ->where('param_1', $request->query('param_1'))
    ->where('param_2', $request->query('param_2'))
    ->where('param_3', $request->query('param_3'))
    ->first();
```

Since this would be executed on each HTTP request, i would suggest caching it.

```
$cacheKey = $request->query('key') . $request->query('param_1') . $request->query('param_2') . $request->query('param_3');
cache()->remember($cacheKey, 14400, function () { // cached for 4 hours
    return ... // your query
});
```

Putting all this logic together, it could look like this. With some minor clean code improvements.

```
const DEFAULT_RATE_LIMITING = 60;

protected function configureRateLimiting()
{
    RateLimiter::for('global', function (Request $request) {
        $rateLimiting = $this->getCacheRateLimiting();

        return $rateLimiting ? $rateLimiting->rate_limit : static::DEFAULT_RATE_LIMITING;
    });
}

private function getRateLimitingDatabase(): ?object 
{
    DB::table('rate_limiting_table')
        ->where('key', $request->query('key'))
        ->where('param_1', $request->query('param_1'))
        ->where('param_2', $request->query('param_2'))
        ->where('param_3', $request->query('param_3'))
        ->first();
}

private function getCacheRateLimiting(): ?object 
{
    // cached for 4 hours
    return cache()->remember($this->getRateLimitingCacheKey(), 14400, function () {
        return  $this->getRateLimitingDatabase();
    });
}

private function getRateLimitingCacheKey(): string
{
    return $request->query('key')
        . $request->query('param_1')
        . $request->query('param_2')
        . $request->query('param_3');
}
```

Comment: Actually I have set the rate limit by storing the entire table in redis and using redisearch I have added the rate limiter. **My worry is that Ratelimiter will work if multiple user sends requests containing multiple combination at the same time?** @mrhn

Comment: But that is really not the question you asked? "Need to add the rate limiter dynamically using the data retrieved from the database table"